# iOS unit test with OCMock static library (the -ObjC flag issue)

Tags: ios, xcode, linker, ocmock

My project is developed with Objective-C. I have a third party framework in use (I name it `thirdparty` here. Sorry, I can't tell the name of the third-party).

Now, I want to write unit test code for my project. I use [OCMock static library](http://ocmock.org/) & I followed its [instruction](http://ocmock.org/ios/) to setup this static library to my iOS project. As you see in their instruction, it asks me to add the `-ObjC` linker flag in **Build Settings -> Other Linker Flags**.

But when I build my project I get the **following error**:

```
ld: warning: Auto-Linking supplied '../thirdparty.framework/thirdparty', 
missing required architecture i386 in file ../thirdparty.framework/thirdparty (2 slices)
```

But, if I remove the added `-ObjC` linker flag from **Build Settings -> Other Linker Flags**, the above error disappears, my project then can be built successfully (but when run my unit test, OCMock library throws error which asks me to add the `-ObjC` linker flag back)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regarding the error, I assume that your 3rd libs do not support i386 architecture. I guess that you experienced that issue when running on Simulator. You should check again whether or not your libs support the targeted architecture. Here is the script to check

```
xcrun -sdk iphoneos lipo -info $(FILENAME)
```

The result shows like this

[image]

So I think the issue might not come from OCMock static lib as long as it supports i386 architecture. You should check again your configuration or other libs as well.

Comment: thanks, so, if my 3rd lib doesn't support i386 architectue, and if I am not able to add the support to this 3rd lib, then, there isn't much I can do to fix this issue, right?

Comment: As far as I know, we couldn't able to do more unless you have original projects of 3rd libs and build by your self, or ask for support from 3rd teams.